# SQL - Reduce the time for joins

Tags: sql-server, join

First of all, I'm very new to SQL.

I have a table with about 500k rows for one single day - `Table1`.

And I'm trying to do two left join for the `Table1` where one table has 10k rows and other table has 200k rows.

The query runs for about 15 mins. Is there any way that we can reduce the time for the joins?

Do we have something similar to Indexing for joining?

I found a topic about `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`, but doing so will the time consumed for the join will be reduced?

Kidnly help me out with this query.

Table1 :

```
sDate   No  Val Val2
01-Jan  1   A   Z
01-Jan  1   B   A
01-Jan  2   C   R
01-Jan  2   D   DF
01-Jan  2   E   F
01-Jan  3   F   DF
02-Jan  3   G   T
02-Jan  3   H   H
02-Jan  4   I   H
02-Jan  4   J   G
02-Jan  5   K   B
02-Jan  5   L   V
02-Jan  1   A   Z
03-Jan  1   B   A
03-Jan  2   C   R
03-Jan  2   D   DF
03-Jan  2   E   F
03-Jan  3   F   DF
04-Jan  3   G   T
04-Jan  3   H   H
04-Jan  4   I   H
04-Jan  4   J   G
04-Jan  5   K   B
04-Jan  5   L   V
```

Left Join Table 1 :

```
No  Lab1
1   P
2   Q
3   A
4   R
5   T
```

Left Join Table 2 :

```
zDate   No  Tab1
01-Jan  1   P
01-Jan  2   Q
01-Jan  3   A
01-Jan  4   R
01-Jan  5   T
02-Jan  1   P
02-Jan  2   Q
02-Jan  3   A
02-Jan  4   R
02-Jan  5   T
03-Jan  1   P
03-Jan  2   Q
03-Jan  3   A
03-Jan  4   R
03-Jan  5   T
04-Jan  1   P
04-Jan  2   Q
04-Jan  3   A
04-Jan  4   R
04-Jan  5   T
```

Query:

```
SELECT [sDate]
    ,[No]
    ,[Val1]
    ,[Val2]
    ,[Lab1]
    ,[Tab1]
FROM [Table1]
LEFT JOIN [Left Join - Table1] ON
    [Table1].[No] = [Left Join - Table1].[No]
LEFT JOIN [Left Join - Table2] ON
    [Table1].[No] = [Left Join - Table2].[No]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u show us some examples with table structures?

Comment: Please give as your table structure and also follow the execution plan in sql, you would see what indexes you need to do in order for the join to work faster.

Comment: @timus20001 - I've updated with the table structure.

Comment: is it complete query? no where condition

Comment: @Neeraj - That's the join query. I store the result in a CTE and perform a `COUNT(*)` with all the columns after the join in completed.

Comment: If you really want some help here you need to post the ddl (create table statements) and index definitions for these tables. A great place for that is sqlfiddle.com. BTW, I hope those are not your real table names.